# OCaml Core List.Assoc.find

Tags: ocaml

I am having trouble running some code from the book Real World OCaml. The code snippet is on [github](https://github.com/realworldocaml/examples/blob/master/code/files-modules-and-programs-freq/freq.ml). In particular, I am getting a type error on line 6:

`List.Assoc.find counts line`

I am using OCaml 4.04.1 and according to utop, the type signature of `List.Assoc.find` is:

`('a, 'b) List.Assoc.t -> equal:('a -> 'a -> bool) -> 'a -> 'b option =
<fun`

Notice the non-optional parameter `equal` that is missing from the code snippet above. But, according to the latest (as of June 2017) [documentation](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/113.33/doc/core_kernel/Core_kernel/Core_list.mod/Assoc.mod/) for `List.Assoc.find`, the `equal` parameter is optional.

What is the purpose of the `equal` parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function looks through a list to find a pair whose first element is equal to the value you give. It returns `Some (snd pair)` or `None` if no equal element is found. The `equal` parameter allows you to specify a definition for equality in case you don't want the built-in `=`.

For what it's worth I currently use OCaml 4.03.0, and I installed Core with OPAM. The `equal` parameter is optional for me:

```
# List.Assoc.find;;
- : ('a, 'b) Core.Std.List.Assoc.t ->
    ?equal:('a -> 'a -> bool) -> 'a -> 'b option
```

Comment: This code works for me:
`let assoc = [("one", 1); ("two",2); ("three",3)] ;;` 
`List.Assoc.find assoc "two" ~equal:(=);;`